# One-Way Operations in WCF Services

Tags: wcf

i am new in wcf. so often read basic tutorial & guide line from many site on wcf. i saw people design their wcf service with special attribute like `[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]`

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IArticleService
{
   [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
   void OneWayMethod();
}
```

after reading on this one-way operation i understand what it is as follow....
When an operation has no return value, and the client does not care about the success or failure of the invocation. WCF offers one-way operations to support this sort of fire-and-forget invocation,: once the client issues the call, WCF generates a request message, but no correlated reply message will ever return to the client

i like to know if i do not specify IsOneWay=true or IsOneWay=false then IsOneWay=true is default. just tell me what happen when we do not specify this attribute IsOneWay=true ?

or specify like IsOneWay=false

thanks

### UPDATE

i read a write up from this url **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isoneway%28v=vs.110%29.aspx** and understand what is the meaning of IsOneWay=true or IsOneWay=false

```
[ServiceContract]
public class OneAndTwoWay
{
  // The client waits until a response message appears.
  [OperationContract]
  public int MethodOne (int x, out int y)
  {
    y = 34;
    return 0;
  }

  // The client waits until an empty response message appears.
  [OperationContract]
  public void MethodTwo (int x)
  {
    return;
  }

  // The client returns as soon as an outbound message
  // is queued for dispatch to the service; no response
  // message is generated or sent.
  [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
  public void MethodThree (int x)
  {
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IsOneway is false by default and you have to explicitly set it to true if you want your operation to be a one way

Check this out :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733035(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if i set explicitly one-way=false then what happen? if my service function return some value the client will not wait to get that value?